# ontouchstart not working on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

I would like to replicate a hover effect on touch devices with javascript. I have created 2 events ontouchstart and ontouchend but for some reason it is not working i get a console error.

error: **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector.**

my code:

```
(() => {
    const hero = document.getElementById('hero');

    if (!hero) {
        return;
    }

    const shuffle = array => {
        let currentIndex = array.length;
        let temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        while (0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    };

    const images = Array.from(Array(16).keys(), n => n + 1);
    const shuffleArray = shuffle(images);

    const init = () => {
        shuffleArray.forEach(image => {
            let imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
            imageDiv.className = `bg-image bg-image-bg${image}`;
            hero.appendChild(imageDiv);

            document.querySelector(imageDiv).ontouchstart = function () {
                imageDiv.style.opacity = 1;
            }

            document.querySelector(imageDiv).ontouchend = function () {
                imageDiv.style.opacity = 0;
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', init);
})();
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should simply be `imageDiv.ontouchstart =`, not `document.querySelector(imageDiv).ontouchstart =`. You don't need to look up a `div` you've just created via `querySelector`. You just use that `div` object as is. Further, `querySelector` only accepts strings as arguments, not element object.

A better approach would be doing this:

`imageDiv.addEventListener('touchstart', your_function_here)`

PS: I'm not even sure `imageDiv.ontouchstart` works at all, instead of using `addEventListener`.